# Flutter: way to validate one sort of google account?

Tags: email, dart, flutter, verification, account

I'm building an app in flutter (latest build) for students on the university. every student has its own email and password (ex. s2170456@student.utwente.nl), which is integrated in google, so everyone is able to see notifications in Gmail.

This does also mean; if you want to log in with google, your studentEmail is an option to do so. I want to implement a google log-in feature where only student of the university (with their email sXXXXXXX@student.utwente.nl) are able to login.

My question is: is there a way to filter on the google login email? I thought about using normal email login and use RegEx to validate, but this means student should firstly signup. I would like to skip the whole sign-up and let the students use their already owned student email to signin.

it should look something like this (if it is even possible) VV

```
Widget googleLogin () {
googleLogin button()
if(googlelogin.email == sXXXXXXX@student.utwente.nl)
    log user in;
} else {
    return error message('invalid email')
}
```

I want this to be able to only register and login user with student email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google sign in integration like this.

```
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
```

then in init state:-

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
   setState(() {
     _currentUser = account;
     print("User Name ${_currentUser.displayName}");
     print("User Email ${_currentUser.email}");
    });

   if (_currentUser != null) {
     var socialData = SocialData(
        _currentUser.displayName, "", _currentUser.email, LoginType.GOOGLE);
     _startHomeScreen(socialData);
   } else {
    _showError('Error, Please try again later');
   }
 });
```

}

on successful login, this will execute:-

```
 _startHomeScreen(SocialData data) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Home(socialData: data);
    }));
  }


     Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
     } catch (error) {
    print(error);
   }
  }
```

Call _handleSignIn() on click of google sign in button.

Comment: is this using the google_sign_in dart package? and how do I validate that the user is a university student, as I do not see any validations? still thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to let anyone sign in but block the users from using the app unless they are using the university mail

```
void handleUser(FirebaseUser user) {
  if(user.email==sXXXXXXX@student.utwente.nl) {
    // handle sign in and UI changes
  } else {
    print('The user is not allowed');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I will try and see if this implementation works for me. I appreciate you helping me :)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark it as the right answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: hello sir. this was a good recommendation, but there is currently no way to create a google login with flutter on firebase. the firebase_auth has removed the signinWith google option and i am not sure how to create a google login now anymore :/

Comment: https://github.com/ammaratef45/Attendance/blob/master/attendance/lib/loginPage/login_page_viewmodel.dart#L22:L31 this is how I handle it in my project, remember to use the same versions of packages in my pubspec file

Comment: thanks! i found another git with the same implementation as yours. i still have some problems with the setstate, as this is giving me errors (setstate called after dispose)

i changed from a login form to google, and there still might be some dirty code. :/
would you mind taking a look?